Lost 1 Sol on a frozen token
Just deposited 2 sol into my wallet. Bought .1 sol of a token and tried to sell but didn't go though. I tried selling over and over and now my account only has 1 sol in it as if I was charged for all those failed transaction fees on this frozen token...

Please provide the token address and which exchange you bought/were trying to sell on, without those, we cannot provide relevant information
